# How I can divide values in a column by specific row in R?

Tags: r

This is a subset of my large data:

```
gene    feature reads
A       anot    2
A       3ss_A   3
A       3ss_B   5
B       5ss_A   1
B       anot    4
C       3ss_A   2
C       3ss_B   8
C       anot    3
C       5ss_A   6
```

I want to divide reads corresponding to 3ss and 5ss features in each gene to feature "anot" of that gene. I have multiple features for each gene (not shown here) but each gene only has one "anot" feature.

expected output is:

```
gene    feature reads   ratio
A       anot    2       1
A       3ss_A   3       1.5
A       3ss_B   5       2.5
B       5ss_A   1       0.25
B       anot    4       1
C       3ss_A   2       0.666666667
C       3ss_B   8       2.666666667
C       anot    3       1
C       5ss_A   6       2
```

How I could do this in R? 
Thanks

Comment: `DF$reads / DF[DF$feature == 'anot', 'reads'][DF$gene]`

Comment: @rawr, Nice solution but note that it does assume the genes are sorted in `DF` (which they are in the question).

Comment: @G.Grothendieck well, alphabetical, correct? they could be sorted but if the levels were not ordered properly, it wouldn't work. plus if they were characters it also wouldn't work

Answer (score 11):

Here are a variety of alternatives:

**1) ave** Use `ave` like this.  The function `fun` is passed the vector of row numbers for one gene and returns the vector of ratios for it.  No packages are used.

```
fun <- function(ix) with(DF[ix, ], reads / reads[feature == "anot"])
transform(DF, ratio = ave(1:nrow(DF), gene, FUN = fun))
```

giving:

```
  gene feature reads     ratio
1    A    anot     2 1.0000000
2    A   3ss_A     3 1.5000000
3    A   3ss_B     5 2.5000000
4    B   5ss_A     1 0.2500000
5    B    anot     4 1.0000000
6    C   3ss_A     2 0.6666667
7    C   3ss_B     8 2.6666667
8    C    anot     3 1.0000000
9    C   5ss_A     6 2.0000000
```

**1a) ave** Here is another approach to using `ave`.  It replaces each non-anot reading with NA and then in each gene it divides the readings by the non-NA using `na.omit`:

```
transform(DF, ratio = 
  reads / ave(ifelse(feature == "anot", reads, NA), gene, FUN = na.omit))
```

giving:

```
  gene feature reads     ratio
1    A    anot     2 1.0000000
2    A   3ss_A     3 1.5000000
3    A   3ss_B     5 2.5000000
4    B   5ss_A     1 0.2500000
5    B    anot     4 1.0000000
6    C   3ss_A     2 0.6666667
7    C   3ss_B     8 2.6666667
8    C    anot     3 1.0000000
9    C   5ss_A     6 2.0000000
```

**1b) ave**  Here is another `ave` variation.  This one is particularly concise but does assume that the `reads` value of `anot` is always non-negative (which is the case in the example in the question). It creates a vector equal to `reads` for `anot` and zero otherwise and then takes the maximum:

```
transform(DF, ratio = reads / ave((feature == "anot") * reads, gene, FUN = max))
```

giving:

```
  gene feature reads     ratio
1    A    anot     2 1.0000000
2    A   3ss_A     3 1.5000000
3    A   3ss_B     5 2.5000000
4    B   5ss_A     1 0.2500000
5    B    anot     4 1.0000000
6    C   3ss_A     2 0.6666667
7    C   3ss_B     8 2.6666667
8    C    anot     3 1.0000000
9    C   5ss_A     6 2.0000000
```

**2) by** An alternative, also not using any packages, is to use `by`.  Here the function `funby` takes a subset of rows of `DF` and returns the subset with the ratio appended on.

```
funby <- function(x) transform(x, ratio = reads / reads[feature == "anot"])
do.call("rbind", by(DF, DF$gene, funby))
```

giving:

```
    gene feature reads     ratio
A.1    A    anot     2 1.0000000
A.2    A   3ss_A     3 1.5000000
A.3    A   3ss_B     5 2.5000000
B.4    B   5ss_A     1 0.2500000
B.5    B    anot     4 1.0000000
C.6    C   3ss_A     2 0.6666667
C.7    C   3ss_B     8 2.6666667
C.8    C    anot     3 1.0000000
C.9    C   5ss_A     6 2.0000000
```

**3) rep/table** This also uses no packages.  It assumes that `DF` is sorted by gene (which is the case in the example in the question).  It repeats each `anot` reading for the number of rows in that gene and then divides `reads` by that.

```
transform(DF, ratio = reads / rep(reads[feature == "anot"], table(gene)))
```

giving:

```
  gene feature reads     ratio
1    A    anot     2 1.0000000
2    A   3ss_A     3 1.5000000
3    A   3ss_B     5 2.5000000
4    B   5ss_A     1 0.2500000
5    B    anot     4 1.0000000
6    C   3ss_A     2 0.6666667
7    C   3ss_B     8 2.6666667
8    C    anot     3 1.0000000
9    C   5ss_A     6 2.0000000
```

**4) dplyr** Using the dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% 
   group_by(gene) %>% 
   mutate(ratio = reads / reads[feature == "anot"]) %>% 
   ungroup()
```

giving:

```
Source: local data frame [9 x 4]

    gene feature reads     ratio
  (fctr)  (fctr) (int)     (dbl)
1      A    anot     2 1.0000000
2      A   3ss_A     3 1.5000000
3      A   3ss_B     5 2.5000000
4      B   5ss_A     1 0.2500000
5      B    anot     4 1.0000000
6      C   3ss_A     2 0.6666667
7      C   3ss_B     8 2.6666667
8      C    anot     3 1.0000000
9      C   5ss_A     6 2.0000000
```

**5) data.table** Using the data.table package:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- as.data.table(DF)
DT[, ratio := reads / reads[feature == "anot"], by = "gene"]
```

giving:

```
> DT
   gene feature reads     ratio
1:    A    anot     2 1.0000000
2:    A   3ss_A     3 1.5000000
3:    A   3ss_B     5 2.5000000
4:    B   5ss_A     1 0.2500000
5:    B    anot     4 1.0000000
6:    C   3ss_A     2 0.6666667
7:    C   3ss_B     8 2.6666667
8:    C    anot     3 1.0000000
9:    C   5ss_A     6 2.0000000
```

**Note:** The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "gene    feature reads
A       anot    2
A       3ss_A   3
A       3ss_B   5
B       5ss_A   1
B       anot    4
C       3ss_A   2
C       3ss_B   8
C       anot    3
C       5ss_A   6"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, there are plenty of ways for this problem! I wanted to use dplyr solution (suggested by G. Grothendieck) on my big dataset but I have got an error. I found that a few genes do not have "anot" in feature column. How I could avoid this? I should filter out genes that do not have "anot" in feature column.

Comment: Perhaps    `mutate(ratio = reads / c(reads[feature == "anot"], NA)[1])` giving `Inf` for the ratio in the case of no `anot`.

Comment: Excellent, it did the job.

Comment: Or maybe this would be better since it gives `NA` for the ratio in the case of no anot:  `mutate(ratio = c(reads / reads[feature == "anot"], NA)[1])`

Comment: Also note that (1b) and (5) handle the no anot case without any modification.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
anot_reads        <- yourdata[yourdata$feature == "anot",]$reads
names(anot_reads) <- yourdata[yourdata$feature == "anot",]$gene
yourdata$ratio    <- yourdata$reads / anot_reads[yourdata$gene]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use, in base R:

```
df$ratio <- unlist(sapply(levels(df$gene),
    function(l) with(subset(df, gene==l), reads / reads[feature=="anot"])))

gene feature reads     ratio
1    A    anot     2 1.0000000
2    A   3ss_A     3 1.5000000
3    A   3ss_B     5 2.5000000
4    B   5ss_A     1 0.2500000
5    B    anot     4 1.0000000
6    C   3ss_A     2 0.6666667
7    C   3ss_B     8 2.6666667
8    C    anot     3 1.0000000
9    C   5ss_A     6 2.0000000
```

It translates as: apply along the levels of `gene` : subset df, divide `reads` by the `reads` value for `feature==anot`. Then you `unlist` the result and create a new column in your `data.frame`.

But there is probably a shorter option.